# My code keeps returning 0 as the number of decimals in a text file

Tags: c++

I made a text file filled with decimals that are separated by a space and I want to count how many there are. the problem is when I came to check if I did it correctly the program says that the number of elements in the file is 0.

```
ifstream dataInput("Data Set.txt");
double readNumber;
vector<int> dataSet;
while (dataInput >> readNumber){
        dataSet.push_back(readNumber);
}
cout << "the Number of elements in this file is " << dataSet.size() << endl;
```

txt file:

```
3.2 1.9 2.7 2.4 2.8 2.9 3.8 3.0 2.5 3.3 1.8 2.5 3.7 2.8 2.0 3.2 2.3 2.1 2.5 1.9
```

My expected result is

```
The number of elements in this file is N.
```

but instead I get:

```
The number of elements in this file is 0.
```

EDIT: Thanks to the people on here I discovered that my file wasn't opening properly. I added the line

```
if (!dataInput.is_open()) {
    cerr << "The file can not be opened\n";
    exit(1);//exits the program
}
```

to check if the file opens properly.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your text file?

Comment: Please [edit]  your question and show the first 6-7 lines of your "Data Set.txt" file. Also consider transforming your code snippet in to a [mcve]

Comment: Likely this is because your file open fails. Always check that you successfully open a file. `if (dataInput.is_open()) ...`.

Comment: Does `dataInput >> readNumber` evaluate to a `bool` value?

Comment: @blackbrandt I added an image link :)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, post text.

Comment: @vahancho the `operator>>` returns the stream and the stream can be implicitly converted to `bool`

Comment: @john I added this just now. if (!inFile.is_open()) {
        cerr << "The file can not be opened\n";
        exit(1);//exits the program
    }

Comment: @vahancho see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt)

Comment: @chtc_pingu And does the file open fail (holds breath) ...?

Comment: @chtc_pingu please don't post code in a comment, as you can see it is rather unreadable. Instead [edit] your question and put your code _there_. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: @john the file does not open :(( What do u guys think is the reason

Comment: You will get 0 if the file does not exist, so you should test for this. Also, please always post complete examples, including #include and the main function...

Comment: @chtc_pingu There can be many reasons but the usual one is that where you think the file should be and where the program is looking for the file are two different things. But then we get into issues such as how you run your program, what operating system you are using etc etc. Things that strictly have nothing to do with C++.

Comment: @john should I just add the specific file location?

Comment: @chtc_pingu Certainly worth trying, if only to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @john that solved it! thank you!

Comment: @Jabberwocky I am really sorry. I am not used to stack overflow yet because I am new. I will remember what u said for my next posts. thank you!

Comment: @chtc_pingu use `dataInput.is_open()` to check if the file has actually been opened correctly.

Comment: @chtc_pingu, please edit your question to include important details like the fact that you've discovered that the file does not open.

Comment: I recommend renaming your file so that it doesn't have spaces.  Some operating systems don't like spaces in filenames; others may need the file name enclosed in double quotes if there are spaces in the filename.

Answer (score 0):

As an advice you should get acquainted with the STL, but be aware that it takes some times to practice. At the end you will be able to write very concise code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    std::ifstream dataInput("./data/TestFile.txt");
    if (!dataInput.good()) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    std::vector<double> dataSet;
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<double>(dataInput), std::istream_iterator<double>(), std::back_inserter(dataSet));
    std::cout << "The number of elements in this file is: " << dataSet.size() << "\n";
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You shouldn't also write `using namespace std` in order to write less code. It is considered a bad practice.

Comment: You don't test if the file could be opened

Comment: @Jabberwocky: That's a good point. In this case my `vector` just remains empty, but the reason is not that the file is not empty.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: I changed it a bit to address this issue. Maybe you have a better solution?

Comment: It looks OK to me now.

Comment: Note:  The OP's filename had a space in it, which may lead to problems; your filename doesn't.

Answer (score -3):

Try to read your file correctly " ifstream dataInput("DataSet.txt"); " you should debug your code to know if you passe this condition

<< while (dataInput >> readNumber) >>